# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Я пытаюсь сделать отправку сообщения в определённый канал с помощью бота на discord.js. Вот код:

```
const channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find((ch) => {
  ch.name === 'appeals'
})

channel.send(`Жалоба:\nАвтор: ${msg.author.username}\nЖалоба на: ${args[0]}\nСтатья: ${args[1]}`)
```

Но мне выдаёт ошибку:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Не могу понять что не так

Comment: На всякий случай — я подправил ответ, убедитесь, что прочитали последнюю версию)

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я могу понять, `msg.guild.channels.cache` содержит массив. Метод массива `find()` возвращает `undefined`, если не находит ни одного элемента, удовлетворяющего условию, это и происходит в вашем случае.

Ошибка в формате стрелочной функции, нужно так:

```js
(ch) => ch.name === 'appeals'
```

Или так:

```js
(ch) => {
  return ch.name === 'appeals';
}
```

Если тело функции облекается в фигурные скобки, нужно явно употреблять оператор `return`, иначе функция будет вовзрващать `undefined` в любом случае, и ничего не будет найдено.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: пожалуйста, пометьте ответ принятым, если ответ помог вам решить проблему